# How do I create a loader that will load in between images when they load in an image slider in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in learning  react, I create a project portfolio using image slider, I want to be able to create a loader in between whenever the image load one after the other.
Here is the link to the code
https://github.com/motuncoded/fatah-website/blob/main/src/components/ImageGuitarSlider.js

Comment: one of multiple ways use `CircularProgress` from material-ui/core

Comment: Please copy your code instead of uploading an image.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not much info to go on, but you can use a `useEffect` to achieve this. Here is a generic example you can start off with: In your `ImageSilder` add a `useState` for loading and in the `useEffect` use a promise with a timeout of 1.5 seconds.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {

    setLoading(true)
    const loadingHandler = () => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve()
            }, 1500)
        
        }
    }
    
    loadingHandler.then(() => setLoading(false))

}, [ticket])
```

Whenever the ticket state is changed it will trigger `useEffect` (we pass the ticket as a dependency to useEffect) which will set the loading state to true, wait 1.5 seconds and set loading to false. You can use this loading state to display a loading icon, for example, a spinner or loading bar.

This may not be a full solution, based on the info provided in your description, it can be a starting point in what you are looking for.

Comment: It is not working, it showing error

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: https://github.com/motuncoded/fatah-website/blob/main/src/components/ImageGuitarSlider.js